# python: use assert to raise different Error types

Tags: python, exception, assert

Using `assert`, you can easily test a condition without needing an `if/raise`:

```
assert condition, msg
```

is the same as

```
if not condition:
  raise AssertionError(msg)
```

My question is whether it is possible to use `assert` to raise different types of `Errors`.  For example, if you are missing a particular environment variable, it would be useful to get back an `EnvironmentError`.  This can be done manually with either a `try/catch` or a similar `if/raise` as before:

```
if not variable in os.environ:
  raise EnvironmentError("%s is missing!" % variable)
```

or

```
try:
  assert variable in os.environ
except:
  raise EnvironmentError("%s is missing!" % variable)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a shortcut of some type that I haven't been able to find, or if there is some workaround to be able to have multiple `except`s up the stack.

Comment: Assert is a debug time feature, that can be disabled or enabled using a special command line flag. You can write a version that does what you need as a function, accepting an optional error class. However, I would generally advise writing it purely rather than as a function that you delegate to, it sounds like sanitising code rather than development asserts

Answer (score 5):

The built-in `assert` is a debug feature, it has a narrow use, and can even be stripped from code if you run `python -O`.

If you want to raise various exceptions depending on conditions with one-liner expressions, write a function!

```
assert_env(variable in os.environ)
```

Or even

```
assert_env_var(variable)  # knows what to check
```

If you want a super-generic / degenerate case, consider a function that accepts *everything* as parameters (possibly with some default values):

```
my_assert(foo == bar, FooException, 'foo was not equal to bar')
```